# I need to make an Ignition Communication with a Database

Tags: mysql, ignition

So I need to make an Ignition communication with a database.
Used Ignition before, I already have a functional database. Created in MySQL and in Ignition, works perfectly, status valid. Now I've made another database, same IP, same port, different name, status Faulted. In MySQL it's running, status OK, in Ignition it doesn't connect.

Ideea? Help.

I wanted to make a new database, exactly like the first one, but the second one has a faulted status.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.

In order to make the actual database we need to go in **MySQL** and select "Create a new schema in the connected server" which is the "create new schema" = "create new database"